# redefinition of function 'main' gtk program

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors, gtk, program-entry-point

i am using gtk to build some GUI with c programming language on windows with codeblocks, but i got some issues with my c programs when I include gtk header files , it show this error

```
error: conflicting types for 'main' 
note: previous definition of 'main' was found here
```

sometime I got this error instead

```
error: redefinition of function 'main'
```

this is my code

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc , char * argv[])
{
    gtk_init(&argc ,& argv);
    GtkWidget * window ;
    GtkWidget * button ;

    window=gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    button = gtk_button_new_with_label("mapp");

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window),button);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

this is the compiler output :

```
||=== Build: Debug in gtk_tables (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\gtk-3.0\gtk\deprecated\gtkvbox.h||In function 'main':|
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\gtk-3.0\gtk\deprecated\gtkvbox.h|29|warning: implicit declaration of function 'gtk_vbox_new'; did you mean 'gtk_hbox_new'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]|
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\gtk-3.0\gtk\deprecated\gtkvbox.h|29|warning: assignment to 'GtkWidget *' {aka 'struct _GtkWidget *'} from 'int' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]|
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\gtk-3.0\gtk\deprecated\gtkvbox.h|40|warning: 'gtk_tearoff_menu_item_new' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]|
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\gtk-3.0\gtk\deprecated\gtktearoffmenuitem.h|77|note: declared here|
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\gtk-3.0\gtk\deprecated\gtkvbox.h|44|warning: 'gtk_image_menu_item_new_from_stock' is deprecated: Use 'gtk_menu_item_new' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]|
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\gtk-3.0\gtk\deprecated\gtkimagemenuitem.h|84|note: declared here|
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\gtk-3.0\gtk\deprecated\gtkvbox.h|44|warning: 'GtkStock' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]|
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\gtk-3.0\gtk\deprecated\gtkvbox.h|46|warning: 'gtk_image_menu_item_new_from_stock' is deprecated: Use 'gtk_menu_item_new' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]|
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\gtk-3.0\gtk\deprecated\gtkimagemenuitem.h|84|note: declared here|
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\gtk-3.0\gtk\deprecated\gtkvbox.h|46|warning: 'GtkStock' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]|
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\gtk-3.0\gtk\deprecated\gtkvbox.h|48|warning: 'gtk_image_menu_item_new_from_stock' is deprecated: Use 'gtk_menu_item_new' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]|
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\gtk-3.0\gtk\deprecated\gtkimagemenuitem.h|84|note: declared here|
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\gtk-3.0\gtk\deprecated\gtkvbox.h|48|warning: 'GtkStock' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]|
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\gtk-3.0\gtk\deprecated\gtkvbox.h|50|warning: 'gtk_image_menu_item_new_from_stock' is deprecated: Use 'gtk_menu_item_new' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]|
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\gtk-3.0\gtk\deprecated\gtkimagemenuitem.h|84|note: declared here|
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\gtk-3.0\gtk\deprecated\gtkvbox.h|50|warning: 'GtkStock' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]|
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\gtk-3.0\gtk\deprecated\gtkvbox.h|83|warning: 'gtk_image_menu_item_new_from_stock' is deprecated: Use 'gtk_menu_item_new' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]|
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\gtk-3.0\gtk\deprecated\gtkimagemenuitem.h|84|note: declared here|
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\gtk-3.0\gtk\deprecated\gtkvbox.h|83|warning: 'GtkStock' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]|
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\gtk-3.0\gtk\deprecated\gtkvbox.h|109|warning: assignment to 'GtkWidget *' {aka 'struct _GtkWidget *'} from 'int' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]|
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\gtk-3.0\gtk\deprecated\gtkvbox.h||In function 'OnTearoff':|
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\gtk-3.0\gtk\deprecated\gtkvbox.h|157|warning: 'gtk_menu_get_tearoff_state' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]|
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\gtk-3.0\gtk\gtkmenu.h|226|note: declared here|
C:\Users\ismail\Documents\Applications\c\New folder\gtk_tables\main.c|7|error: conflicting types for 'main'|
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\gtk-3.0\gtk\deprecated\gtkvbox.h|11|note: previous definition of 'main' was here|
C:\Users\ismail\Documents\Applications\c\New folder\gtk_tables\main.c||In function 'main':|
C:\Users\ismail\Documents\Applications\c\New folder\gtk_tables\main.c|15|warning: assignment to 'GtkWidget *' {aka 'struct _GtkWidget *'} from incompatible pointer type 'GtkWindow *' {aka 'struct _GtkWindow *'} [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 16 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: Seems correct to me, can you please shoy the full output of the compiler? (O.T; `gtk.h` already includes `stdio` and `stdlib`, you don't need to include them)

Comment: @DavidRanieri i have edited my question , i removed the stdio and stdlib they were not the problem, the problem is still there ; i also added the compiler outputs ;

Comment: Check this thread: https://github.com/tschoonj/GTK-for-Windows-Runtime-Environment-Installer

Comment: Certainly I'm not the only one curious what is present on line #11 of `C:\msys64\mingw64\include\gtk-3.0\gtk\deprecated\gtkvbox.h`

Comment: @WhozCraig what happens at line 11?

Comment: Well, thats the question.

Comment: Here, on Linux, line 11 is in the middle of a license comment block...

Comment: @WhozCraig this is what i found on line 11  ```#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
void OnQuitter(GtkWidget* widget, gpointer data);
void OnAbout(GtkWidget* widget, gpointer data);

int main(void )
 ```

Comment: It looks like you have a corrupt install of gtk ` gtkvbox.h` should not contain any of this crap. Try removing and reinstalling.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. i don't think so , i used to work with that just fine but now I don't know what causes the problem, I will reinstall gtk and see

Comment: If it's not the GTK installation itself, then perhaps it's the compile command or flags?

Comment: Hi, please check if removing (int argc , char * argv[]) params from your main() function will help. Of course remove gtk_init(&argc ,& argv); line also.

Comment: If `C:\msys64\mingw64\include\gtk-3.0\gtk\deprecated\gtkvbox.h` contains any of this: `#include <stdlib.h> #include <gtk/gtk.h> void OnQuitter(GtkWidget* widget, gpointer data); void OnAbout(GtkWidget* widget, gpointer data);  int main(void )` it has been corrupted. It should look similar to this: [https://code.woboq.org/kde/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/deprecated/gtkvbox.h.html](https://code.woboq.org/kde/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/deprecated/gtkvbox.h.html)

Comment: @drescherjm i think that's it , my file maybe corrupted ;I will change it or at least reinstall gtk

Comment: This may help: [https://www.msys2.org/wiki/MSYS2-reinstallation/](https://www.msys2.org/wiki/MSYS2-reinstallation/)

Comment: @drescherjm thanks a lot , indeed the file is corrupted i removed it and everything works just fine